# IntelliJ IDEA 15 RC2 (build 143.380.20) - Grails - Debug Mode

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, grails-3.0

**I'm using:**

- IntelliJ IDEA 15 RC2 build 143.380.20
- Java build 1.8.0_66-b17
- Grails 3.0.9

**When try run my project in debug mode:**

[image]

**get this error:**

```
        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:44719,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:/home/felansu/Software/idea-IU-143.380.20/plugins/Groovy/lib/agent/gragent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-
    ...
   gsp/3.0.9/123055121c92e0f2242e225a3204ec96d3bd26a9/grails-plugin-gsp-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-web-databinding/3.0.9/fe946b1cb1fdc2cbc9effaf370daae064c3e244/grails-web-databinding-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-services/3.0.9/6228151e6af140603dcf2f6fa1aa59c44709677a/grails-plugin-services-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-web-url-mappings/3.0.9/93da24f625113f3395b0188b498ce6ad357560b3/grails-web-url-mappings-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-url-mappings/3.0.9/4a7fb37f8fce82e7bc70253acecb9eb6ecd3a49a/grails-plugin-url-mappings-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-web-jsp/3.0.9/770b6a58a7879bae3150f2ffcc7fec2264261961/grails-web-jsp-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-web-mvc/3.0.9/122cdf12141a07da44bf58ec1342f164c089b249/grails-web-mvc-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-interceptors/3.0.9/d3ec73124762cae052cdf06b450222b8a58a2cde/grails-plugin-interceptors-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-web-sitemesh/3.0.9/327a5da810e34116bb380110233646f5a2239071/grails-web-sitemesh-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-async/3.0.9/fcc550590bd3d9663b454bc024d4ec419fc7f007/grails-plugin-async-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.4.5/4c7cd3b294af0a32609402c9d12ccc4218890e12/groovy-2.4.5.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.7.RELEASE/5e4c9931acaf2857efe5f1ad27e4791c0855b8b2/spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-sql/2.4.5/a8a1b9eb0a1282940b4d41a43ca5df5178d70fb3/groovy-sql-2.4.5.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor.spring/reactor-spring-context/2.0.6.RELEASE/1408e5ae689d3aca8b910ad2f39fce080a646feb/reactor-spring-context-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.0.6.RELEASE/777a92012c60278a98311e2aa787dc8eeced758d/reactor-bus-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.4.1/2231238e391057a53f92bde5bbc588622c1956c3/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-json/2.4.5/ff21b54d65128ff46488286af056eed606481f97/groovy-json-2.4.5.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.1.7.RELEASE/2d9245006b788d7d6afeec85a43e4bfe2e46340a/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-taglib/3.0.9/ce82f5557ed1831d469f063657184556b6dae4f0/grails-taglib-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support/4.0.7.RELEASE/1026cd86782451c6cb903439fcbbffc267cc58bb/grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.1.7.RELEASE/d8923bdffe631904899875e719d8b363bc3deaea/spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor/reactor-core/2.0.6.RELEASE/a36e58c9d2d0ac1f47e17e8db60a7ebb9d09789c/reactor-core-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor/reactor-stream/2.0.6.RELEASE/d41c8242ea2dcb0d2c661ad0ff9c25401501b861/reactor-stream-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-web-common/3.0.9/e827f35c12e72309956997baddbb360b8d4b38ba/grails-web-common-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4/4.0.7.RELEASE/fda9cb99545b213e60c64bebfec651203ecd0df7/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-web-taglib/3.0.9/ed2bf00d65a2b14969bba8f4b36505120d23be5/grails-web-taglib-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-ant/2.4.5/da3bf324dd8480f6f94e6f6a6af3fdea7cc03af4/groovy-ant-2.4.5.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor.spring/reactor-spring-core/2.0.6.RELEASE/8eb6c6f4df6e40bf5caff119374e71b0cb8351e8/reactor-spring-core-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/536ac0021240d97db99c7d2983067cef1a6f3af5/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-datastore-web/4.0.7.RELEASE/7e7655bab97e0ffefe9a1db726965bc8e09aea51/grails-datastore-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.0/14b8c877d98005ba3941c9257cfe09f6ed0e0d74/reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-groovydoc/2.4.5/ab5ed761a967b9a42bca862f037816215de9287e/groovy-groovydoc-2.4.5.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-controllers/3.0.9/3ce2c16cb56505bcdff729126835f88d6029c130/grails-plugin-controllers-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/8e20852d05222dc286bf1c71d78d0531e177c317/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-domain-class/3.0.9/b243fe02bb2bae0e5b495847d9b85a88706ef3b3/grails-plugin-domain-class-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-mimetypes/3.0.9/53cb4bb671863da99a5f5e55612e8fd8797c583d/grails-plugin-mimetypes-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-converters/3.0.9/dda6f99c416e8b779d4d546429381dcf4ab2f14a/grails-plugin-converters-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-codecs/3.0.9/bd3bdc41677a02ec26ed6e2f9b64aa4a83ec748e/grails-plugin-codecs-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.4.6/3e63a25de4065697b185f523ed5e020c0db3ff0/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.7.RELEASE/8c6c02bcccfa23a74db59f7b7725e69e1af38f04/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-xml/2.4.5/bbbb0cdd8a566362454372adb1601f0c052e51c6/groovy-xml-2.4.5.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-web/3.0.9/de9d39704fbacd42e3fa596020b0384921bc6ec7/grails-web-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-datasource/3.0.9/493c46792f426d91236b36bd4d821ce2db0ff2f4/grails-plugin-datasource-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-core/3.0.9/2b7e80af2fd277baded711cf5b94af0b9a8bf15b/grails-core-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.6/7108cf65148f29a55ebf23db2c46224ea9d086dc/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-logging/3.0.9/2a997e860869f6554b2091e3e0e1e344129637fb/grails-logging-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-web-gsp-taglib/3.0.9/fc2ca2f8461aee3a90a1d37c29fa72154fca230/grails-web-gsp-taglib-3.0.9.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.1.7.RELEASE/3465a5d3b24006d51482cf45abd13e347f64582a/spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails.plugins/asset-pipeline/3.0.8/95bf23fd5e4bed45ff56328cc395ca695d76f498/asset-pipeline-3.0.8.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails.plugins/scaffolding/3.1.2/70559775aa9169ee155a70dd1a66f271eccdccee/scaffolding-3.1.2.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.bertramlabs.plugins/asset-pipeline-core/2.5.0/984bc7cb66366f07a0ed8fe1bb21ca0c6bf8dacc/asset-pipeline-core-2.5.0.jar:/home/felansu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails.plugins/fields/2.1.0/670b525afca7dffd7c5a73b7baecb441fab4c2e8/fields-2.1.0.jar:/home/felansu/Software/idea-IU-143.380.20/lib/idea_rt.jar qrbws.Application
        Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:44719', transport: 'socket'
        ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
            at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:140) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:290) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:486) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:276) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:52) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:330) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:319) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
            at qrbws.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
            ... 27 common frames omitted
        Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:44719', transport: 'socket'
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
            at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:140)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:290)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:486)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:276)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:52)
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:330)
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:319)
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
            at qrbws.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 27 more

        Process finished with exit code 1
```

And this don't allow run the project in debug mode.
Exist an issue open [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136970)

Answer (score 0):

[Daniil Ovchinnikov](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/user/daniil.ovchinnikov) solved my problem, just change my dependency spring-boot-starter-tomcat 'provided' to 'compile'. Thanks!

Comment: However, you need that dependency to be "provided" if you want to build a war without embedded tomcat.